# Is there a way to get the COMMENT from mysql columns using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to get the comments from all columns I have created. Is that possible using PHP? I will give you an example. This is a simple comment I have created:

```
ALTER TABLE `car_comfort` CHANGE `BoardCom` `BoardCom` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'demo';
```

In this case the comment is `demo`. Can I extract the comment of the column `BoardCom` using PHP?

Comment: @u_mulder, should i delete my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query catalog view [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html) for this:

```
select column_comment
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'car_comfort' and column_name = 'boardcom'
```